# Long SQL subquery trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just registered and want to ask.
I learn sql queries not so long time and I got a trouble when I decided to move a table to another database. A few articles were read about building long subqueries , but they didn't help me. 
Everything works perfect before that my action.
I just moved the table and tried to rewrite the query while whole day.

```
update [dbo].Full
set [salary] = 1000
where [dbo].Full.id in (
    select distinct k1.id
    from (
        select id, Topic, User 
        from Full
        where User not in (select distinct topic_name from [DB_1].dbo.S_School)
    ) k1
    where k1.id not in (
        select distinct k2.id
        from (
            select id, Topic, User 
            from Full 
            where User not in (select distinct topic_name from [DB_1].dbo.Shool)
        ) k2,
        List_School t3
        where charindex (t3.NameApp, k2.Topic)>5
    )
)
```

I moved table `List_School` to database `[DB_1]` and I can't to bend with it. 
I can't write `[DB_1].dbo.List_School`. Should I use one more subquery? 
I even thought about create a few temporary tables but it can influence on speed of execution.

Sql gurus , please invest some your time on me. Thank you in advance.

I will be happy for each hint, which you give me.

Comment: This doesn't look a lot like MySQL

Comment: Why can't you write `[DB_1].dbo.List_School`? That should be perfectly valid in MS SQL Server (this looks like SQL Server syntax to me), and also you're using very similar `[DB_1].dbo.Shool` already.

Comment: What's the version of MySQL? (if it actually is MySQL and not SQL Server)

Comment: dbo is a sign this is really Sql Server. Changing the tag.

Comment: Please paste the Original SQL that was working, and label it as such.  Then clearly tell us the OldTableName(s) and the NewTableName(s) because there are a few differences above.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a number of issues. You are comparing the user column to the topic_name column.  An expected meaning of those column names would suggest you are not comparing the correct columns.  But that is a guess.

In the final subquery you have an ansi join on table List_School but no join columns which means the join witk k2 is a cartesian product (aka cross join) which is not what you would want in most situations. Again a guess as no details of actual problem data or error messages was provided.